# Name clash between multiple uses of collectionView in subclass of UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios9

How can I overcome the following apparent name clash. A subclass of `UICollectionViewController` contains these method definitions, both by way of conforming to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, 
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // ...
    let interimSpacing = collectionView(collectionView, 
        layout: collectionView.collectionViewLayout, 
        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex: indexPath) // <-- ERROR
    // ..
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, 
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

The Swift compiler (in Xcode 7.1.1) marks the indicated line with this error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'UICollectionView'

How can I sort out this apparent name clash between multiple uses of the identifier `collectionView` in this piece of code?

**UPDATE** I have also tried renaming the parameter in the first method definition like so `func collectionView(x: ...` but the problem remains.

Comment: You shouldn't have the collectionView: label on the first parameter of your method call.

Comment: @CharlesA. Thx. Fixed this. Underlying problem remains.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps using `self.collectionView` to distinguish from the parameter will clear things out to the compiler?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Nops, did not yet work for me (see answer below).

Comment: Can you put in the code where your first `// ...` is?  Also, as @CoryWilhite points out in his answer, you're passing `indexPath` instead of `indexPath.section`.

Comment: @CharlesA. I was stupid in passing `indexPath`. Thx (also) for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let interimSpacing = self.collectionView(collectionView, layout: collectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex: indexPath.section)
```

your original delegate method on the collection view wasn't passing in the correct parameters that you were receiving from the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method.

Edit: you should also note that the sectionAtIndex requires the indexPath.section and not the entire indexPath

Comment: I duplicated your code and this worked. Did you replace the entire line? Your code is also passing in an NSIndexPath in a parameter that requires an Int aka the .section of the indexPath...